# Connecting to Zapier doesn't working

Tags: zapier, litespeed

I just move my website from Apache server to Litespeed server
I reconnect Zapier/integromat but it notices:
Error

401: Invalid response, response must be a XML. Parsed HTML response: 401 Unauthorized.      401. Unauthorized. Proper authorization is required to access this resource!. Proudly powered by  Please be advised that LiteSpeed Technologies Inc. is not a web hosting company and, as such, has no control over content found on this site.

Please help me what reason and how to fix this. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

more look like a migration problem instead of the Web server. You should contact your hosting company for details. They can switch between Apache and LSWS, also check the error log for you. You may also need to provide detailed URL for your hosting company to take a look.